# Material UI : CardMedia Round Image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new in full stack developing and I'm trying to code something to understand better frontend with React JS and Material UI. I've used a card component to show posts in backend but I want to show profile image (via CardMedia) circular, so I've decided to override the component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import DeletePost from './DeletePost'
import PostDialog from './PostDialog'
//MUI
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles'
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ChatIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Chat'
import MyButton from '../../utils/MyButton';

const styles = {
    card: {
        display: "flex",
        marginBottom:20,

    },
    image:{
        minWidth: 100,
        minHeight: 100,
        borderRadius: '50%',
        objectFit: 'cover'
        
    },
    content:{
        objectFit: 'cover'
    }
    
    

}

class Post extends Component {
return (
            <Card className={{root: classes.card}}>
                <CardMedia
                    image={userImage}
                    title="Profile image"
                    className={classes.image}
                    />
                    
                    
                    <CardContent className={classes.content}>
                        <Typography 
                            variant="h5"
                            component={Link} 
                            to={`/users/${userHandle}`} 
                            color="primary">
                            {userHandle}
                        </Typography>
                        {deleteButton}
                        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                            {dayjs(createdAt).fromNow()}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body1">{body}</Typography>
                        
                    </CardContent>
            </Card>
        )
}
Post.propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    openDialog:PropTypes.bool
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    user: state.user
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Post));
```

But the image looks oval and stretched. How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and it is difficult to diagnose the issue. Can you post your full code?

Comment: I've added all my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your css for the image, you've set a minHeight and minWidth. You'd want to explicitly set the height and width to equal px. Let me know if that works.